# create json from list with javax.json

Tags: java, json, extjs

I have a List with 3000 items and I have to create a json from it and send it to my client side code which is Extjs. As JsonArrayBuilder does not accept list, I'm iterating through the list and add create each json object and finally send it to the client side. The problem is that this process takes 13 seconds which is really high.

Here is the way I make this json array.

```
 JsonObjectBuilder builder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
 JsonArrayBuilder childrenArrayBuilder = Json.createArrayBuilder();
        builder.add("success", true);
        builder.add("children, childrenArrayBuilder);
```

here is how I iterate through the list

```
           for (TagDefinitionProject tt : myList) {

            childrenArrayBuilder.add(
                    Json.createObjectBuilder()
                    .add("id", getTreeNodeId(tt.getTag()) + "-" + (idSplit[1]))
                    .add("nodeStatus", tt.getStatus())
                    .add("text", tt.getNJTagName())
                    .add("tagNJName", tt.getTag().getName())
                    .add("baseType", tt.getTag().getBaseType().getName())
                    .add("definitionType", def)
                    .add("leaf", (tt.getTag().getChildren().size() == 1 || tt.getTag().getChildren().get(1).getChild().equals(tt.getTag()))));
            }
```

How can improve the performance here?

Comment: Can you pls post the complete methode/code that takes so long?

Comment: yes, I added my loop which is problematic part.

Comment: Is the stored object "heavy"? Can you share more information on this. Have you tried to compared with a lower number of objects, just to make sure that there is not such  a thing like a "special" case that takes much more time than the usual one?

Comment: Yes I have tried with lower number of objects and it worked fine. Its not heavy at all.

Comment: I tried it with 600 items and there was no problem in sending the response to client side.

Comment: So I would recommend t he "critical" amount or compare with another library  ike gson https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/. It is always helpful to profile, if there is everything fine but after increasing the number of objects strange behaviour is starting. HTH

Answer (score 4):

The preferred method of creating multiple builders with the javax Json library is by using JsonBuilderFactory. I've modified your code below.

```
     // Create a new factory. The argument, config, can be null or
     // contain a Map with configuration values for the created builders.
     JsonBuilderFactory factory = Json.createBuilderFactory(config);
     JsonObjectBuilder builder = factory.createObjectBuilder();
     JsonArrayBuilder childrenArrayBuilder = factory.createArrayBuilder();
            builder.add("success", true);
            builder.add("children", childrenArrayBuilder);


               for (TagDefinitionProject tt : myList) {

                childrenArrayBuilder.add(
                        factory.createObjectBuilder()
                        .add("id", getTreeNodeId(tt.getTag()) + "-" + (idSplit[1]))
                        .add("nodeStatus", tt.getStatus())
                        .add("text", tt.getNJTagName())
                        .add("tagNJName", tt.getTag().getName())
                        .add("baseType", tt.getTag().getBaseType().getName())
                        .add("definitionType", def)
                        .add("leaf", (tt.getTag().getChildren().size() == 1 || tt.getTag().getChildren().get(1).getChild().equals(tt.getTag()))));
                }
```